# how can i stop live reload only for assets folder in angular 7

Tags: angular, livereload

I want to stop live reload for assets folder only because when I compile app.componets.ts it saves 3 new CSV files. Live reload consider as changes so I need to stop live reload only for an assets folder.

Comment: can you add the code which creates CSV ?

Comment: ```ng serve --live-reload false``` seems to be the only solution as of now to prevent reloading.

Comment: I tried all excludes and it still didn't work, it is outrageous, It's angular 12 and it still doesnt work. The only solution is still ng serve --live-reload false

Answer (score 0):

You exclude files to watch changes for in Live Reload by adding the directory or files on to your tsconfig.json "exclude" property.

```
"exclude": [
        "assets/my_csvs"
]
```

Comment: This won't work if the code is using the CSV files by importing or requiring it.